# Allow Detached RCP View to go behind main workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I'm looking to have a view, that has been detached by the user, be able to be placed in front and behind the main application window. Has anyone ever dealt with this before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse RCP detached views: How to control the z-index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978640/eclipse-rcp-detached-views-how-to-control-the-z-index)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is to change the Shell style of the detached window, so you can setup it to behave like a independente window, like if its an another application.

See this post: [How to create my own shell to replace the shell created in the MTrimmedWindow in e4 RCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209828/how-to-create-my-own-shell-to-replace-the-shell-created-in-the-mtrimmedwindow-in)